# How to get post data as json in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am making an ajax request to my API but my API expects raw json data to parse its own objects in C# how do I get the raw Json data in C#? from the "HttpContext.Current.Request"

Here is my request:

```
            $.ajax({
            url: '/REST/GetResponse.cshtml',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "Application/JSON",
            data: {
                code: "login",
                data: {
                    username: $("#login_username").val(),
                    password: $("#login_password").val(),
                    rememberMe: $("#rememberMe").val()
                }
            },
            success: function (result) {

            },
            error: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get body of the request using property 'HttpRequest.InputStream`. The type of the property is a stream, but you can see an example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx) on how to convert it to string.

Depending of what is your underlying framework there can be easier ways to get the body. E.g. MVC of Web API use binding to map incoming requests to objects, so it might be an option to consider.

Comment: I did that which returns something like this "code=login\u0026data%5busername%5d=admin\u0026data%5bpassword%5d=password\u0026data%5brememberMe%5d=First+Choice"